# Parse JSON to TextViews

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, textview

So im parsing JSON data from a API Enabled website, It requires authentiucation by a APIKEY, My issue is that im trying to parse the data then insert it into TextViews on the UI. My current code previously used to use a `HashMap` and a `ListView` However now im trying to change it to just populate the data into the `TextViews`. Currently, I've started changing the code over and now im getting `RunTimeExceptions` with my current code. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

### Issue Resolved

```
public class ParseMoreDetails extends Activity {
private Context context;
private static String url = "https://api.company.com/api/systems?";

private static final String TAG_SYSTEM = "systems";
private static final String TAG_SYSTEM_ID = "system_id";
private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
private static final String TAG_SYSTEM_NAME = "system_name";
private static final String TAG_SYSTEM_PUBLIC_NAME = "system_public_name";
private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";

TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
TextView textView3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);

    new ProgressTask(ParseMoreDetails.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    ArrayList<String> arrfortextviews;
    private ParseMoreDetails activity;

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ParseMoreDetails parseMoreDetails) {
        this.activity = parseMoreDetails;
        context = parseMoreDetails;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

    /** application context. */
    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> success) {
        if(arrfortextviews.size() >0){
                textView.setText(success.get(0));
                textView2.setText(success.get(1));
                textView3.setText(success.get(2));
         }
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
         arrfortextviews=new ArrayList<String>();
        // Using APIKEY from strings.xml
        String apikey = getString(R.string.apikey);

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + "&key=" + apikey);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                String vcolor = c.getString(TAG_SYSTEM_ID);
                String vfuel = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                String vtread = c.getString(TAG_STATE);


                arrfortextviews.add(vcolor);
                arrfortextviews.add(vfuel);
                arrfortextviews.add(vtread);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return arrfortextviews;

    }

 }
```

Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="System ID: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="State:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="..." />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Current Errors

- RuntimeException - NullPointerException
- Leaked Window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView

### LogCat - UPDATED

```
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at com.jitesh.androidjsonparser.ParseMoreDetails$ProgressTask.doInBackground(ParseMoreDetails.java:116)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at com.jitesh.androidjsonparser.ParseMoreDetails$ProgressTask.doInBackground(ParseMoreDetails.java:1)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 05-01 10:27:47.040: E/AndroidRuntime(28236):   ... 5 more
 05-01 10:27:55.035: I/Choreographer(28236): Skipped 464 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236): Activity com.jitesh.androidjsonparser.ParseMoreDetails has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4285c818 that was originally added here
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.jitesh.androidjsonparser.ParseMoreDetails has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4285c818 that was originally added here
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:402)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at com.jitesh.androidjsonparser.ParseMoreDetails$ProgressTask.onPreExecute(ParseMoreDetails.java:86)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at com.jitesh.androidjsonparser.ParseMoreDetails.onCreate(ParseMoreDetails.java:63)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 05-01 10:27:55.210: E/WindowManager(28236):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post error log for us to understand better.

Comment: @sat Updated Code and Included LogCat

Comment: looks like maybe you did not add ParseMoreDetails to your manifest perhaps?

Comment: in error log it points ParseMoreDetails.java:43, apparently there is ann issue at line 43 of ParseMoreDetails.java, can you show that line ?

Comment: @OnurA. i've reupdated the code, please take a 2nd look.

Comment: hımm ok but in your ParseMoreDetails java file, which line is line 43 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Here :

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);  //<<< here
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);//<<< here
TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);//<<< here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
```

you are using `findViewById` before setting layout for current Activity .so you will need to move all Widgets initialize inside `onCreate` method of Activity after setting layout for it. Change your code as:

```
TextView textView,textView2,textView3;  //<<<declare here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  //initialize all textViews here
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
  textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
  ......
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I've updated the code per your recommendations - However im still getting RuntimeExceptions. You mind taking a 2nd look at the code.

Comment: **First Issue is:** pass current Activity to `ProgressDialog` as `dialog = new ProgressDialog(ParseMoreDetails.this);` **Second issue is :** you are trying to update UI elements from `doInBackground` which is not right way to updating UI elements from `AsyncTask` . for updating UI elements when `doInBackground` execution complete use `onPostExecute`

Comment: @P  Thanks for the reply, Updated code per you recommendations, Placing this code `textView.setText(systemID);
   textView2.setText(city);
   textView3.setText(state);` Inside `onPostExecute` I cannot figure out what code i need to transfer there, What about my `JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

     String systemID = c.getString(TAG_SYSTEM_ID);
     String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
     String state = c.getString(TAG_STATE);
` Im now getting the following `systemID cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Did you mean changing `dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);` to `dialog = new ProgressDialog(ParseMoreDetails.this);` in my `ProgressTask` Made the change however still having the same issue - i've updated code in question.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment : ok, just change ParseMoreDetails Activity code as http://pastebin.com/vZjccDeg

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment : use this http://pastebin.com/1S8Cch0Y code in which i have solved all issues as in existing code snippet

Answer (score 0):

you are having an error in doInBackround of the AsyncTask

I suspect that

```
// getting JSON string from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + "&key=" + apikey);
```

returns null

put this line instead may be it will work

```
  // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url + "key=" + apikey);
```

you shouldn't handle UI elements (TextViews) from doInBackground OnPostExecute is made for that

Comment: Tried the change of the `&key=` however no change. Thanks for the answer